# Unresolved table after changing connection

Tags: business-objects

I have encountered a problem after i changed my DSN from POC server to point to my new Testing server without realizing that both environment tables columns are not in sync. There are 2 columns missing in my POC server which exist in both Test and Production server.

After i re-pointed the Universe's DSN to the test server, how do i refresh the existing table in my universe to auto refresh the 2 missing columns? Below is what i have tried:

1. I tried to drag the missing columns into the existing table but it was not allowed.
2. I tried to delete the existing table and drag out the entire table with same name, the 2 missing columns finally appears, but it create more issues as all my existing dimensions created were screwed up due to an "Unresolved table". It seems that it found that the original table was deleted and the new one is not matched.
3. There is no refresh table function available.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I found a workaround. I can still add a new dimension to point to the missing column with no problem. The leftover now is why the data foundation table is not refresh..

Answer (score 0):

Select the table, then hit View->Refresh Structure.